# Connect 2 different networks

Tags: networking

I have this situation 
[Networks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvZIH.png)

So i need to connect the PC1 that is running Ubuntu with the PC2.
I add with the route add command to the route table the follow information 
`route add -net 172.17.0.0 netmask  255.255.0.0 gw 172.17.0.100 dev eth0` 
but still i cannot ping the Router2 or the PC2 .... whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that is missing is to do the same on the other side: your packets are going but nothing is coming back, since Router 2 does not know that 192.168.1.76 is behind 192.168.1.1.